# Can't update my schematic to PCB layout in Altium

Tags: pcb, pcb-design, circuit-design, altium

I have finished my schematic for an echo circuit using PT2399 IC as per the application circuit in datasheet. I have downloaded the part (including footprint) from snapeda.com and updated my Altium library. But I can't update the design to PCB. There's no option as 'Update PCB document' under the 'Design' tab to update the design to PCB. But it is showing for other projects I have done. I don't understand. Please help me, it's urgent.

Comment: At risk of insulting MegaMind (which is not my intention) but do you have a .PcbDoc setup in the .PrjPcb?  And, is this "update PCB" function grayed-out or just not there?

Comment: Thank you so much Steve. Actually I'm new to this Altium. This is my first project besides a simple power supply which I did to learn this and it was done some time ago and honestly I forgot. Thank you sir.

Comment: No worries there MegaMind.  I, was baptized-by-fire (no formal training) learning Altium so I understand the possible frustration/s.

Answer (score 1):

Altium Designer is similar to, for example, Microsoft Visual Studio and other major development applications, in the sense that you can open a single document or an entire project (collection of related documents).

When you have just a PCB or schematic document open, Altium has no context for updating one from the other. If you have the *project* open — even if you only have one schematic within it actually *open* — then Altium 'knows' which PCB you want to update.

The file extensions of interest (per Altium 19) are:

- `PrjPcb` = The entire project
- `PcbDoc` = PCB
- `SchDoc` = Schematic

*(It may help to have [file extensions shown](https://superuser.com/a/494323/8811).)*